# MYSQL filter on multiple dates as array

Tags: mysql, sql, date

The code below works like it should, but now I want to add multiple dates like this:

reservationStartDate = 2018-07-16, 2018-07-17

```
SELECT 
    *,
    SUM(IF(reservationId IS NULL,
        0,
        reservationStartDate = '2018-07-17')) AS ConflictingReservations
FROM
    units
        LEFT JOIN
    reservations ON (unitsId = reservationSpace)
WHERE
    unitsType = 'room1'
GROUP BY unitsId
HAVING ConflictingReservations = 0;
```

Comment: Use `IN` clause.

Comment: @PM77-1 In an `IF` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just do:

```
SELECT u.unit_id,
       SUM(r.reservationStartDate IN ('2018-07-17')) AS ConflictingReservations
FROM units u LEFT JOIN
     reservations r
     ON u.unitsId = r.reservationSpace
WHERE u.unitsType = 'room1'
GROUP BY u.unitsId
HAVING ConflictingReservations = 0;
```

Or, even more simply:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM units u LEFT JOIN
     reservations r
     ON u.unitsId = r.reservationSpace AND
        r.reservationStartDate in ( . . . )
WHERE u.unitsType = 'room1' AND r.reservationSpace IS NULL;
```

No `GROUP BY` is needed at all, because you are not using the count.

Answer (score 1):

Use `OR`

```
(reservationStartDate = '2018-07-16' OR reservationStartDate = '2018-07-17')
```

---

The complete query would be

```
SELECT 
    *,
    SUM(IF(reservationId IS NULL,
        0,
        (reservationStartDate = '2018-07-17'
            OR reservationStartDate = '2018-07-17'))) AS ConflictingReservations
FROM
    units
        LEFT JOIN
    reservations ON (unitsId = reservationSpace)
WHERE
    unitsType = 'room1'
GROUP BY unitsId
HAVING ConflictingReservations = 0;
```